# Relationships not displaying properly under CiviCRM 5.70

Tags: relationships

I had an issue previously whereby relationships were not being displayed , similarly notes. After a while I was provided with an answer in that a couple of entries were missing in the SearchKit and I was provided with copies of these to import which fixed my issue so all good.

Now after installing 5.70 Notes is still working but for relationships all I can get displayed are the expired ones.

I have checked the relationship and relationship_cache tables and they seem fine with cache being twice the size of relationship.

So my question is whether or not the code that I was given for the previous releases is still valid or is there another version I need to import?

[image]

This is what I see when looking at the relationships:

[image]

Comment: I fixed it myself. As I suspected the "old" versions of the searches weren't valid under 5.7.0 so I created a dummy site , installed CiviCRM 5.7.1 , exported the search , re-imported it into my production site and the relationships started to appear

Comment: So, I guess what @paulbutler is saying is that the Packaged Searches in the SearchKit are old/outdated for Notes and Relationships.  Can you give me good ones and show me how to import a Packaged Search? Thanks!!